# get the id of the currently click element and get the children id too

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

is there a way I could get the id of the currently click element and its child id in angular? like in jquery, I can just do

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var this_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var child_id = $(this).find("div").attr("id");
});

<a href="#" id="this_parent_id">
    <div id="this_child_id"></div>
</a>
```

any ideas, clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use $event

```
$scope.myClickFunction = function(obj, $event){
    console.log($event.target);
}
```

"Directives like ngClick and ngFocus expose a $event object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a jQuery Event Object when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object." [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a ng-click attribute to the anchor and pass the `$event`. The ng-click will call the getIDs function and print the parent and child IDs

```
<a href="#" id="this_parent_id" ng-click="getIDs($event)">
    <div id="this_child_id"></div>
</a>

$scope.getIDs = function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.id); // Gets clicked element ID
    console.log(ev.target.firstElementChild.id) // Gets child ID
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpj85xuv/1/)

Comment: sadly i got this erro "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" after running your code. any ideas?